# Does Don Bradman Cricket on PS3 feature a versus mode?

Tags: ps3, don-bradman-cricket-14

Apparently, there's no co-op mode in the game, but does it feature a one on one mode, where two people can play against each other on a single console? Like FIFA does.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't a CO-op mode before but they have released a new patch for PS3 and 360 users adding the co-op feature. I'm a PC user so I haven't tested but this new patch would be the final patch for Don Bradman Cricket 14 as they'll be heading on to release a new game this year.

http://www.cricketgaming.net/news/new-co-op-patch-for-don-bradman-cricket-14-is-released-for-ps3-and-xbox-360/103047/